# how to setup virtual attributes with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I come from a `Rails` background and am attempting to use `AngularJS with Rails`.  I am stuck on a very simple thing:  how does one construct what rails calls 'virtual attributes' in an `Angularjs environment`?  Let me give an example.

I have a rails model, called Medication, and it has two attributes, dosage and count.  I want to have a 'total' virtual attribute that returns dosage * count.  This is trivial in Rails, since it is just an instance method of class Medication.

So, how does that map into the `AngularJS` world?

Clarification:  I am using an ng-repeat directive on Medications (plural) for which I have a `MedicationsController`.  For each ng-repeat loop, I get a '`medication`' object, where I want to apply this 'instance method'

```
total = function() { return dosage * count }
```

How is that coded? Where do I put the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really simple with AngularJS as you can use any JavaScript function in AngularJS view. So just define a function on your object (or directly on a scope). For example, give a controller like this:

```
var MedicationCtrl = function($scope) {    
    $scope.medication = {
        dosage : 0.5,
        count : 10,
        total : function() {
            return this.dosage * this.count;
        }
    };
}​
```

You can simply write:

```
Total: {{medication.total()}}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r5g5/1/

Then, if you've got a collection of items and don't want to put any logic on an object level, you can define this method on a controller like so:

```
var MedicationCtrl = function($scope) {    
    $scope.total = function(medication) {
      return medication.dosage * medication.count;
    };
};
```

and use this function from a markup like follows:

```
<ul ng-repeat="m in medications" ng-controller="MedicationCtrl">
    <li>{{m.dosage}} + {{m.count}} = {{total(m)}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the above code in the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r5g5/3/

Comment: I need to clarify on this:  I am using an ng-repeat directive on Medications (plural) for which I have a MedicationsController.  For each ng-repeat loop, I get a 'medication' object, which is what I want to apply the function total()

Comment: Updated the answer but I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do, exactly. It would be easier if you could send a jsFiddle with your actual code.

Comment: OK, got it.  Thanks a lot.  Trying to map Rails behavior onto AngularJS has its pitfalls.  I didn't recognize that I needed a 'singular' controller for Medication as well as a 'plural' controller for Medications, as an array of Medication 'objects'.  There really isn't any equivalent to a Ruby instance method, they are really more like helper methods. Maybe, by convention, I should call my new controller a 'MedicationHelperController'.  I also noticed that the item keyword in the ng-repeat directive could not be 'medication', since nothing worked if that was the case.